# How to get on-chain data on pallet?

Tags: offchain-worker

I want to get some 'trustful' on-chain data on the pallet, for example, get transaction data by transaction hash. I found Offchain Workers might do that job but is it really trustful because the API can fail or return incorrect data.

Comment: what do you mean by 'on-chain data on pallet' and 'on-chain data on the pallet'? i think you mean you want to write code in the pallet implementation itself, such as in an extrinsic function or in `on_initialize` or `on_finalize` that will try to get transaction data by transaction hash that may have been stored in that pallet's storage and where the associated data was originally generated off-chain, and that on-chain data may not be trustful unless you accompany each storage item with a timestamp of when it was stored along with flagging missing data based on benchmarked response times

Comment: Hi Luke, you are right. In my case, my node integrates Frontier and I want to implement the dispatchable function to get EVM transaction data by the transaction hash. What do you think is the appropriate solution to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Any data you want to retrieve from the runtime and runtime logic must be stored.

So if you want to be able to get a transaction by the hash within the on-chain environment, you will need to store a map of all the transaction hash values to the corresponding data.

However, this will make your state really large, and is probably not the recommended thing to do.